# When / why would I ever want to raise an exception on a method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've noticed that some methods in rails use the `!` operator to raise an exception if invalid.  For example, `User.create!`

Why and when would I want to use something like this?

Thanks.

Comment: Pedantic nit: that `!` isn't an operator, it's part of the method name. It sometimes means _operate on the data in-place_ -- depending upon the API in question.

Comment: It's not really a pedantic nit, though; while `!` is an operator, it *isn't* an operator when it's part of a method name, like `create!`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[ActiveRecord will roll back a transaction if an exception is thrown while a transaction is active](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Rollback.html).

So the methods that throw exceptions are nice to ensure the database doesn't commit a transaction when an exceptional condition occurs. When you can "handle" the problem yourself -- or, if it isn't actually a problem -- then you can use the variant without the `!`, check the return value for error conditions, and handle them yourself.

For something specific like `User.create`:

- You might use the `User.create` method to determine if a user-supplied username is not yet picked and provide a prompt for the user to select another name, if it is already in use.
- You might use the `User.create!` method when finally submitting the request, so that your integrity checks can fail the create and rollback the transaction in case the user attempts bypassing your friendly name check.

Comment: And by the way: the author calls the symbol `!` as *operator*. It's not right for the case: this symbol is just a part of the method's name, so there are two different methods, say, `create!` and `create`. It's Ruby feature -- many other languages don't allow such symbols so it's easy confuse them with operators.

Answer (score 6):

I could want exceptions for various reasons

- I might want to make sure that the method succeeds but I don't want to do any actual error handling here. But I might be fine with the request blowing up (e.g producing an HTTP 500) if something fails
- I might want to have some error handling elsewhere, e.g some way up in the call chain. Generally, it's way more verbose and nasty to pull some error state with you a long way towards error handling. Structured error handling, i.e., `begin ... rescue ... end` make that clearer.
- Exceptions can have additional data attached (e.g. an error message)
- If you have different error types, it often much clearer to represent those with different exception classes instead of some magic id values (as is common in C)

There are good reasons to not use exceptions but status flags when the error states are few in number and are fully handled directly after the call. But every technique has its place and time.

And btw, the `save` method internally calls `save!`, handles the potential exception and returns false if there is any. See [the code](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v3.2.3/activerecord/lib/active_record/persistence.rb#L68-88) for the implementation.